# Setting mode through a function in Emacs Lisp

Tags: elisp

I have the following code in my `.emacs` file, which works as you'd expect:

```lisp
;; Ruby
(global-font-lock-mode 1)
(autoload 'ruby-mode "ruby-mode" "Ruby editing mode." t)
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.rb$" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.rsel$" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.rhtml$" . html-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.erb$" . html-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.prawn$" . html-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("Rakefile$" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

However, my attempts to DRY it up a bit fail:

```lisp
(defun set-mode-for-filename-patterns (mode filename-pattern-list)
  (mapcar
    (lambda (filename-pattern)
      (setq 
        auto-mode-alist 
        (cons '(filename-pattern . mode) auto-mode-alist)))
    filename-pattern-list))

;; Ruby
(global-font-lock-mode 1)
(autoload 'ruby-mode "ruby-mode" "Ruby editing mode." t)
(set-mode-for-filename-patterns 
  ruby-mode
  '("\\.rb$"
    "\\.rsel$"
    "\\.rhtml$"
    "\\.erb$" 
    "\\.prawn$"
    "Rakefile$"
    "Gemfile$"))
```

... with the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable ruby-mode)
  (set-mode-for-filename-patterns ruby-mode (quote ("\\.rb$" "\\.rsel$" "\\.rhtml$" "\\.erb$" "\\.prawn$" "Rakefile$" "Gemfile$")))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/duncan/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1768
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/duncan/.emacs" "/home/duncan/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil "\205\264
```

I'm a bit confused here ... in particular, I don't understand how `ruby-mode` is void & so can't be passed to a function, but *can* be `cons`ed into a pair?

Any pointers (heh) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the form:

```
(cons '("\\.rb$" . ruby-mode) ...
```

`ruby-mode` is part of a quoted list. That means it is read as a symbol name, not evaluated as a variable. In other words, Emacs sees it as the symbol `ruby-mode` and accepts it as is.

In the form:

```
(set-mode-for-filename-patterns 
   ruby-mode
   '("\\.rb$"
     "\\.rsel$"
     ...
```

`ruby-mode` is not quoted, and so is read as the argument to a function. Function arguments are evaluated. Which means Emacs reads `ruby-mode`, recognizes it as a symbol, and tries to evaluate it. Evaluating a symbol means looking for the value that it points to, which in this case doesn't exist.

EDIT:

Your function still doesn't work, there's another problem. You've used a quoted list inside `set-mode-for-filename-patterns`. This works fine in your original code:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.rb$" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

as you are in effect manually supplying the *value* for `filename-pattern` and `mode`. Inside your function, you need these symbols to be *evaluated*, which doesn't happen when they're quoted! The result is that instead of adding each different string from your list to auto-mode-alist, you get the symbol `filename-pattern` instead.

To fix this, you need to recognize that the '(filename-pattern . mode) is meant to produce a cons cell with the *values* of `filename-pattern` and `mode`. Which we can produce with (cons filename-pattern mode). So the corrected function would be:

```
(defun set-mode-for-filename-patterns (mode filename-pattern-list)
  (mapcar
    (lambda (filename-pattern)
      (setq 
        auto-mode-alist 
        (cons (cons filename-pattern mode) auto-mode-alist)))
    filename-pattern-list))
```

And the corrected function call is:

```
(set-mode-for-filename-patterns 
  'ruby-mode
  '("\\.rb$"
    "\\.rsel$"
    "\\.rhtml$"
    "\\.erb$" 
    "\\.prawn$"
    "Rakefile$"
    "Gemfile$"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.rb$" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
----------------------------^
```

This is a `quote` which means you prevent the evaluation of the next
form, thus `'("\\.rb$" . ruby-mode)` is equivalent to `(cons '"hello"
'ruby-mode)`.

But when you call the function `set-mode-for-filename-patterns` the
arguments are first evaluate then their result is passed to the
function. That's why evaluation `(set-mode-for-filename-patterns
ruby-mode ..)` raise an error, because the emacs-lisp interpreter tries
to evaluate `ruby-mode` as a variable, but `ruby-mode` has no value in
this context hence the error `(void-variable ruby-mode)`. What you
want here, is to pass the symbol `ruby-mode` so you have to quote it
like this `(set-mode-for-filename-patterns 'ruby-mode ...)`

Note that you could have set a value to `ruby-mode` mode with `let`.

```
(let ((ruby-mode 'ruby-mode))
  (set-mode-for-filename-patterns ruby-mode ...))
```

Here when the argument the form `(set-...)` is evaluated it evaluates
`ruby-mode` and can find a value for it (which is the symbol
`ruby-mode`) and then pass it to the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think `set-mode-for-filename-patterns` is an interesting function. I'm going to add it to my config but use a more optimized implementation.

The implementations here all add one item to the `auto-mode-alist` variable for each file suffix. Emacs searches this list every time it finds a file. So the shorter the `auto-mode-alist`, the faster Emacs will find files.

This version is probably slower at startup but faster when finding files:

```
(defun set-mode-for-filename-patterns (mode filename-pattern-list)
  (push (cons (regexp-opt filename-pattern-list) mode)
        auto-mode-alist))`
```

This will work with the the same call:

```
(set-mode-for-filename-patterns 
   'ruby-mode
   '("\\.rb$"
     "\\.rsel$"
     "\\.rhtml$"
     "\\.erb$" 
     "\\.prawn$"
     "Rakefile$"
     "Gemfile$"))
```

If you look at the value of `auto-mode-alist` you'll see that many of the built-in modes use regexps for the same performance reason.

BTW, I advise that you just trust `regexp-opt` to do the right thing. The regexps it makes are pretty hard on the eye (and brain).

Comment: The members of the argument list passed to `regexp-opt` cannot themselves be regular expressions. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027783/how-can-i-cons-a-list-of-pairs-on-to-auto-mode-alist/11030085#11030085