# How can I cons a list of pairs on to auto-mode-alist?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a long list of files and file extensions which I would like to have Emacs open automatically in ruby-mode. From using Google, the most basic solution that works is this:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\.rake$"    . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\.thor$"    . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("Gemfile$"   . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("Rakefile$"  . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("Crushfile$" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("Capfile$"   . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

Which seems way repetitive to me. Is there a way I could define the list of pairs once and either loop or cons it directly onto `auto-mode-alist`? I've tried

```
(cons '(("\\.rake" . ruby-mode)
         ("\\.thor" . ruby-mode)) auto-mode-alist)
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need a single regexp (and hence entry in `auto-mode-alist`) to match all those options, and you can let `regexp-opt` do the work of building it for you.

```el
(let* ((ruby-files '(".rake" ".thor" "Gemfile" "Rakefile" "Crushfile" "Capfile"))
       (ruby-regexp (concat (regexp-opt ruby-files t) "\\'")))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons ruby-regexp 'ruby-mode)))
```

If you especially want individual entries, you might do something like this:

```el
(mapc
 (lambda (file)
   (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
                (cons (concat (regexp-quote file) "\\'") 'ruby-mode)))
 '(".rake" ".thor" "Gemfile" "Rakefile" "Crushfile" "Capfile"))
```

Comment: Thank you! One question - what is the difference between "let" and "let*"?

Comment: With `let*`, each local binding expression can see the local bindings generated by the previous expressions in the list. In this instance I needed to see `ruby-files` in order to set `ruby-regexp`. See: `C-h f let* RET` vs `C-h f let RET`.

Comment: I'll add that `rx` can also be used to conveniently produce the regexp for the first approach: `(rx (or ".rake" ".thor" "Gemfile" "Rakefile" "Crushfile" "Capfile") eos)`

Answer (score 1):

`cons` takes an item and a list and returns a new list with that item at the head. (for example `(cons 1 '(2 3))` gives `'(1 2 3)`)

What you want to do is take a list and a list and `append` them together

```
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (append '(("\\.rake" . ruby-mode)
            ("\\.thor" . ruby-mode))
   auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: You should adjust your example so that the return value of `append` is actually assigned to `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: @MoritzBunkus My example was modeled after the original post (where he wasn't assigning the result of cons)

Comment: Well, he cannot use the result of your `append` as an argument for his `add-to-list`, so your argument doesn't make much sense to me. Why not provide a fully working example? It's not that much more work.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite would be

```
(push '("\\(\\.\\(rake\\|thor\\)\\|\\(Gem\\|Rake\\|Crush\\|Cap\\)file\\)\\'" . ruby-mode) auto-mode-alist)
```